# Problems with http://wall.plasm.it/examples/example-the-wall/ - Images

Tags: mootools, javascript-framework, imagesource

It is probably piece of cake for You, but I'm in the black hole now and I don't know what is the problem with The Wall. I would like to do something as www.wall.plasm.it/examples/example-the-wall/. Please - look at: www.megainstal.pl/ there is not any images. Could You help with fix it? I will be really grateful for any help/information.

Short story:
1) I download the files from github: https://github.com/plasm/the-wall
2) I changed only 3 files:

```
01-wall.css, 
index.html, 
01-wall.js
```

(case: basic)

3) in 01-wall.js I declared images:

```
var a = new Element("img[src=../../img/middle/"+counterFluid+".jpg]");
```

4) images that are: 1 to 76.jpg

Could you point me to where I making a mistake? If You going to see source files - I zip that's all in the one file: www.megainstal.pl/files.zip

I contact with author of plasm and he told me that I've mistakes in: 
1) width and height size image - I improved
2) window.addEvent("domready", function() … not definite in 01-wall.js - I improved but I have doubt. Please - look at the code:

```
// Define 01-wall.js
var maxLength    = 76; // Max Number images
var counterFluid = 1;
var wallFluid = new Wall("wall", {
                "draggable":true,
                "inertia":true,
                "width":150,
                "height":150,
                "rangex":[-100,100],
                "rangey":[-100,100],
                callOnUpdate: function(items){
                    items.each(function(e, i){
                        var a = new Element("img[src=public/img/middle/"+counterFluid+".jpg]");
                            a.inject(e.node).fade("hide").fade("in");
//THERE
        // Behaviour on click
                                a.addEvent("click", function(e){
                                    // Get Movement
                                    if( wall.getMovement() ){
                                        //(move)
                                    }else{
                                        //(no move)
                                    }
                                })
//THERE
                        counterFluid++;
                        // Reset counter
                        if( counterFluid > maxLength ) counterFluid = 1;
                    })
                }
            });
// Init Fluid Wall
wallFluid.initWall();
```

Please - help me with this troubles. I really need the Wall ;)